# How to batch delete records using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

How can we batch delete a number of documents using PyMongo?

If we start off with a list of docs,

```
docs = list( db.animals.find({'color':'red'}) )
```

Doing the following does not actually remove anything from the collection!

```
toRemove = [x['_id'] for x in docs]
db.animals.remove(toRemove)
```

What is the proper way of batch removing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`remove`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) the same way you use `find`.

If the following line returns the records to be removed:

```
db.animals.find({'color':'red'})
```

then this will remove them:

```
db.animals.remove({'color':'red'})
```

If you already have a list of IDs to remove, you can remove with a filter on the `_id`, using the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator, like this:

```
db.animals.remove({'_id': {'$in': idsToRemove}})
```

Answer (score 0):

While some helper method to remove an array of documents may exist that I am unaware of, I would say the best and most explicit way is to use a loop:

```
for docId in toRemove:
    db.animals.remove({'_id':docId})
```